# Why it is showing like cannot use type float for Boolean in Cplex?

Tags: optimization, error-handling, boolean, constraints, cplex

While doing an optimisation problem, l am stuck with an error. The error side it is showing like cannot use type float for Boolean.

Comment: Can you share your model so that other users could try ?